# Calculate LLOC С++

Tags: c++, c

Пожалуйста посоветуйте, чтоб не изобретать велосипед.

Задача: расчет [LLOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code). Нужен код, готовая реализация не подходит.

Вопрос: возможно, есть код парсера, который реализует похожие задачи. Пож. подскажите ссылку. Если такой реализации нет, подскажите статейку о похожих парсерах, чтоб не начинать решать задачу с нуля.

Заранее большое спасибо за Ваше время.

P.S. К сожалению подсчет ‘;’ или ‘/n’ и т.д. не подходит как упрощенный вариант решения.

ОК, осознаю ошибку и постараюсь уточнить все детали:

1. Общая задача: Подсчёт количества ЛОГИЧЕСКИХ строк кода (т.е. количество операторов в программе). В данном случае весь код в одном файле для которого надо посчитать LLOC.
2. Язык С++, язык анализируемого кода С++
3. Лямбды считать не надо, я должен был это указать сразу.
4. В анализируемом коде также не используются функции (макросы и проч.) из библиотек, все определено в этом же файле. Т.е. тело ф-й и макросов доступно для анализа.

Я понимаю, что подводных камней в данной задаче может быть много, но в данном случае то, что я не указал, можно не учитывать.
Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Ээээ... А чем не подходит подсчёт `\n`? Что в вашем понимании есть LLOC?

Comment: Если вам нужно подсчитать statement'ы, как прикажете считать лямбды? Что делать с макросами, раскрывающимися в несколько statement'ов? Короче, приведите полное формальное определение LLOC. И готовьтесь писать полновесный парсер.

Comment: Ну определение в вики. там даже есть ссылка. http://maultech.com/chrislott/resources/cmetrics/. Просто у меня мало времени, возможно кто-то такую задачу уже решал, и может предложить готоую схему. Как по мне, так часто случаются ситуации требующие написания такого рода парсеров.

Comment: И все-таки вам нужно дать полное и точное определение (функциональную спецификацию) прямо в вопросе. В общем-то с этого любой программный проект начинается, так что вам в любом случае будет полезно написать такой документ. На вопросы VladD обязательно стоит ответить, т.к. это ключевые вопросы, которые могут определять не просто детали, а целиком архитектуру решения.

Comment: @Andriy: По вашей ссылке определения не нашёл, в вики тоже. Отсюда просьба сформулировать его явно.

Comment: @VladD, ну [SLOC как-то же люди считают](https://www.openhub.net/p/python/analyses/latest/languages_summary) (думаю, автор интересуется именно ими а не неизвестым (и мне тоже) LLOC)

Comment: @avp: SLOC — это просто, это количество `\n` в коде. А LLOC — это если верить википедии как бы логическая строка, то есть `while (true) printf("hello world\n");`, даже написанное в одну строку, должно считаться двумя логическими (L) строками кода (LOC). Но поскольку можно накидать много сложных примеров (например: `int x = { int z = rand(); for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) z += f(z); z };`, то в общем случае определение LLOC не вполне понятно.

Comment: @VladD, ага, я тоже прочитал в вике про LLOC (и SLOC). / Почему-то раньше считал, что SLOC это количество `\n` минус комментарии и пустые строки. Т.е. только строки форматированного кода. / А с учетом определения LLOC в вике вопрос-то совершеннно нормальный (имеющий какую-то практическую ценность и очевидно, не решаемый "на коленке"), если считать, что автор адресовал его *компетентным* в этой теме людям. Т.е. это еще один **неправильно закрытый** вопрос.

Comment: @avp: Вопрос-то хороший, но на мой вкус я бы потребовал точного определения LLOC. И любое правильное решение требует полновесного, настоящего парсера языка.

Comment: @VladD, а нужно-ли это для практики? Я бы попробовал начать с какого-нибудь indent (посмотрел, конечно, какие там возможны настройки), из выхода выбросил комментарии, пустые строки и строки только с разными скобочками (хвосты, если они будут). Но, конечно, тут надо экспериментировать.

Comment: ОК, осознаю ошибку и постараюсь уточнить все детали:
1. Общая задача: Подсчёт количества ЛОГИЧЕСКИХ строк кода (т.е. количество операторов в программе). В данном случае весь код в одном файле для которого надо посчитать LLOC.  
2. Язык С++, язык анализируемого кода С++
3. Лямбды считать не надо, я должен был это указать сразу. 
4. В анализируемом коде также не используются функции (макросы и проч.) из библиотек, все определено в этом же файле. Т.е. тело ф-й и макросов доступно для анализа. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Andriy: Имеет смысл добавить эту информацию в вопрос, иначе, боюсь, его никогда не разблокируют.

Comment: @Andriy: А #include как считать? Например, такая конструкция: `#define X 1 #include "generate.h" #define X 2 #include "generate.h" #undef X`, где в файле generate.h `int f ## X () { return X; }`

Comment: @VladD: Вы слишком глубоко копаете, необходимо просто посчитать операторы, инклюды и макросы и проч., можно опустить, это можно будет добавить потом. Меня смущает как получить цифру: 2 логические строки кода (Оператор цикла for и оператор вызова функции printf) из: for (i=0; i<100; ++i) printf("привет"). Если перебирать файл по символам. Данное определение приведено в вики, я на него опираюсь

Comment: @VladD: просто меня пугает альтернатива парсить все ключевые слова... это явно неправильно

Comment: @Andriy, я думаю, что все макросы (а также ифдефы и инкдлюды) надо считать в одном файле. Иногда они могут составлять значительную часть кода. А вот внутрь включаемых файлов лезть не нужно (хотя, может оказаться полезным вывести список всех потенциально включаемых (независимо от условной трансляции) файлов).

Comment: @avp: А если в header'е находится #define, который меняет семантику кода? Например, `#define struct 0;`. Ну, допустим, что это можно пропустить, но это на мой вкус чересчур сильное упрощение.

Comment: @VladD, то что во включаемых файлах, это LLOC этих файлов (а не рассматриваемого). Тут то же самое, что и со строками исходников библиотек. / Кстати, а сколько голосов за повторное открытие нужно набрать этому вопросу?

Comment: @avp: Уже есть 4, так что нужен 1. Я отрекламировал вопрос в C++-чате, но там полтора участника.

Comment: Ага, я уже голосовал, может кто-нибудь еще найдется (из закрывавших активистов?)

Comment: @VladD: я с Вами и avp согласен, что упрощения могут быть критическими, но надо с чего-то начать, учет макросов можно добавить потом, а анализ вложенных файлов в третью очередь, про случаи изменения семантики кода как и про лямбды речь не идет это слишком сложно. Основной вопрос как избежать перебора ключевых слов. И спасибо за голосование за разблокирование вопроса.

Comment: @Andriy, я посмотрел сорсы GNU indent. К сожалению он не понимает C++. Видимо можно взглянуть (и разобраться, сам я до сих пор толком не разбирался) на [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). Вполне вероятно, что их разбора окажется вполне достаточно для выделения LLOC

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, у вас есть два пути: сложный, но честный и нечестный, но очевидный.

Сложный, но честный путь — это использование готового парсера (то есть, *синтаксического* анализатора) C++. Например, вы можете использовать готовый [парсер clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html), там есть библиотеки, предназначенные для включения в другие программы.

При помощи парсера вы получите полное синтаксическое дерево, соответствующее разбору вашего файла, и вам останется лишь обойти его и подсчитать количество узлов, соответствующих statement'ам. Сама по себе интеграция с парсером нетривиальна (плюс не так-то просто скомпилировать его), но зато дальнейший ваш код достаточно простой. Плюс вы автоматически получаете полную поддержку всех фич языка: макросы, лямбды, инклюды и прочее становятся решённой проблемой.

---

Нечестный, но очевидный путь — написание собственного ограниченного по возможностям парсера (т. к. полный парсер писать тяжело, да он вам и не нужен). Здесь можно попробовать применить эвристический подход.

Сначала, выбросьте из файла все директивы препроцессора (возможно, при этом надо будет увеличивать счётчик LLOC, как верно заметил @avp) и комментарии (не забывайте заменять комментарии на пробелы, т. к. они разделяют слова). Затем, замените последовательные пробельные символы (пробелы, переводы строки, табуляцию) на один пробел. Замените все строки на пустые, а символы на `'0'`. В результате этого у вас останется `;`, `{` и `}` лишь в качестве разделителя statement'ов.

Теперь, вам нужно поделить код на LLOC'и. Пробегайте текст слева направо до ближайшей фигурной скобки или точки с запятой — они являются границей LLOC'а. Исключение: цикл `for` содержит точку с запятой, не разделяющую LLOC'и, вам придётся отлавливать это исключение вручную.

Следующее исключение — управляющие структуры языка: `while`, `if`/`else`. Конструкция `while (i > 0) i--;` является двумя statement'ами. Так что вам придётся отлавливать и этот случай.

Примерный алгоритм в этом случае такой.

Начинаем с начала LLOC'а. Пробегаем пробелы, смотрим на первое слово. Если это ключевое слово `while`, `if` или `for`, увеличиваем счётчик LLOC'ов, пропускаем пробелы, открывающую круглую скобку, сбалансированное по скобкам выражение до закрывающей круглой скобки (просто заводим счётчик открытых/закрытых скобок, и выходим, когда он достигнет значения 0). Если это ключевое слово `do`, просто пропускаем его. Продолжаем с начала.

Если ключевое не найдено, пропускаем текст до ближайшей точки с запятой или фигурной скобки (открывающей или закрывающей). Если пропущенный текст состоит лишь из пробелов, ничего не делаем, иначе увеличиваем счётчик LLOC'ов на 1. Пропускаем точку с запятой или скобку, начинаем с начала.

Вам ещё придётся подумать, не нужна ли специальная обработка для объявлений функций и классов/структур.

Да, это много ручной работы. Sorry for that. У вас реально сложная задача.

---

Возможно, второй подход будет проще, если вы проведёте токенизацию (то есть, *лексический* анализ) текста — разобьёте его на токены. В таком случае вам не нужно будет возиться с удалением строк или поиском ключевых слов, это сделает этап лексического анализа.

Comment: @Andriy, (это я чтобы автор тоже получил нотификацию) с собственным разбором остается несколько вопросов по LLOC. Например, `fputs(...), fflush(...);` это 1 LLOC или 2? Аналогично с операторами присваивания внутри выражений типа `if ((n = scanf(...)) < 3) ...`  (видимо тут надо просто принять *волевое решение*). А вот с выбрасыванием директив препроцессора из числа LLOC я не согласен. Значительная часть логики некоторых программ может быть сделана именно на уровне препроцессора.

Comment: @avp: Насчёт препроцессора согласен, погорячился. В качестве альтернативы, можно при выбрасывании увеличивать счётчик. Но тут тоже возможны подводные камни. Например: `#ifdef 0 { #endif` сбивает весь подсчёт :-(

Comment: @avp: Поэтому, возможно, надо пропустить через препроцессор? Но тогда для корректного выбора реально компилируемой части кода (если куски отключаются через `#ifdef`) нужно реально пройти все инклюды. В общем, честное решение тем и хорошо, что таких проблем оно не создаст.

Comment: @avp: А ещё без эмуляции или прогона препроцессора можно случайно потерять ключевое слово (например: `#define MYFOR for ... MYFOR(...`).

Comment: Если пропустить через препроцессор, то мы получим совсем другие LLOC (много чего может подтянуться из /usr/include). А вот про  `#ifdef 0` я не подумал ... Конечно, делать полноценный препроцессор для вычисления выражений в `#if` это пребор. Может ограничиться распознаванием именно констант для `#if 0`?

Comment: Да, с макро для заголовков циклов (и if/switch) это  тоже проблема, если дальше не блок `{ ...}` а один оператор (его-то мы и потеряем).

Comment: @avp: Препроцессор MSVC кладёт в код комментарии, которые говорят, какому оригинальному файлу соответствует код. Наверняка то же самое делают и другие. То есть можно найти эти комментарии, и скипнуть всё, что относится к включённым файлам.

Comment: @avp: Но это может развернуть однострочный макрос в длинную многострочную конструкцию. Так что решение не без побочных эффектов.

Comment: IMHO clang решение будет страдать тем же самым (раскрытие макроса). (похоже, за основу надо брать код препроцессора :))

Comment: @avp: Возможно, clang можно заставить выдать дерево до раскрытия макросов. Или нет. С макросами на самом деле много проблем. Например, под макросом `X` может скрываться например `while (true) x++;` Поэтому без раскрытия макроса нельзя однозначно сказать, будет ли строка `X x = 1;` одной или многими LLOC (в частности, является ли X отдельной LLOC, или это просто объявление типа наподобие `int`).

Comment: Мне все же кажется, что использование макроса нужно рассматривать точно так же, как вызов функции. Проблема в распознавании текста сразу за макросами, моделирующими операторы for, if, ... (или на самом деле ее нет (вот, уже запутался)? Ведь Ваш алгоритм справляется с `if (a > b) puts("OK");` ?)

Comment: @avp: Мне кажется, проблема в том, считать ли макрос отдельной LLOC. Он может быть логически как законченным statement'ом, так и просто ключевым словом и тем самым частью внешнего statement'а.

Comment: @avp: Например, такой макрос: `#define LOGFAILURE fprintf(stderr, "Total failure\n");`. Обратите внимание на `;` в конце макроса. Текст `LOGFAILURE exit(1);` по сути является двумя LLOC. Но мой алгоритм этого не поймёт без препроцессора.

Comment: @Andriy, (и @VladD) выскажу крамольную мысль. Если `for (int i = 0; cond(i); incr(i)) cout << i;` (и т.п. конструкции, даже занимающие несколько строк) договориться считать **одним LLOC**, то это здорово упростит задачу. (Автор, ау!!!)

Comment: @avp: Тогда и `while (cond) {... }`?

Comment: Да, в таком случае `while` и `if` тоже. Но, мне самому что-то это предложение перестало нравится. Слишком оно радикально. / По хорошему (Вы оказались правы в одном из первых комментариев), для определения LLOC надо какую-то формальную грамматику написать. Боюсь, для C++ это будет сложным делом. Например, `MACRO func(arg);` без анализа, что такое MACRO, непонятно -- это декларация переменной func с инициализацией или 2 LLOC исполняемого кода? / Сложная задача.

Comment: @avp: Если бы не препроцессор, всё было бы лучше. По сути, программа на C++ — это две программы в одной.

Comment: Точно. Поэтому даже компилятор правильного ответа не даст. Как минимум нужно добавить к препроцессору вывод псевдокомментариев о начале-конце подстановки макро (такая инфа об инклюдах уже есть), добавить ее к функциям строящим дерево разбора (clang?) и тогда можно будет аккуратно решить задачу. Вот что интересно, кто-нибудь уже проделал это для C/C++?

Comment: @avp: Я не слышал о готовом решении. Есть похожая по смыслу разработка для C# (roslyn), который является общей библиотекой как для компилятора, так и для разбора текста в редакторе, и поэтому держит всю промежуточную информацию, включая текст комментариев, пробелы и позицию в редакторе.

Comment: Похоже есть [что-то](http://msquaredtechnologies.com/m2rsm/) начиная с 200 баксов, но насколько хороши именно LLOC (у них такого термина нет) неясно.

Comment: @Andriy, тут:   http://msquaredtechnologies.com/m2rsm/rsm_demo.php есть какая-то free версия анализатора кода. Попробуете, как она с макросами разбирается?

Comment: @VladD: Большое спасибо за потраченное время, я понимаю, что 'глубина' решения данной задачи имеет очень широкий диапазон. На данный момент, думаю оптимальным решением зажачи реально является написание своего, крайне ограниченного по возможностям парсера. Главное написать его так, чтоб на будущее возможно было ужобно расшитять его фугкционал. Думаю написание парсера предложенного Vlado'm вполне соответствует данному мне ТЗ.

Comment: Я думаю, что если  учесть все озвученные Вами и avp задачи, то проще реально искать для покупки готовое решение. Еще раз большое спасибо, по мере выполнения возможно возникнут вопросы, поэтому если Вам не сложно загдяните сюда в четверг (27.08)

Comment: @Andriy: Если вы напишете здесь комментарий с обращением через `@`, я получу нотификацию. Удачи вам, у вас сложное задание!