# Как посчитать строки кода в файле на C++?

Tags: c++

Идея такая: читать построчно файл, если найдено что-то из набора символов:

```
'\t', ' ', '\n', '{', '}', '(', ')', ';', '\r'
```

то считать, что это строка с кодом и увеличивать счетчик.

Как это реализовать на C++? Интересует сама проверка строки (есть ли в ней что-либо из набора выше).

Comment: Функция strchr() служит для поиска символа в строке.

Comment: Если вы читаете файл _построчно_, как в строке может оказаться `\n` или `\r`?

Comment: А что вы будете делать со строкой `i++; j++;`? Это вы посчитаете за _одну_ строку кода? А что с таким: `for( <newline> i = 0; <newline> i < 1; <newline> i++)`? Это будут 4 строки кода?

Comment: А символы внутри строк и комментариев вы тоже будете считать?

Comment: VladD, какой вариант вы предлагаете?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удалите все комментарии и пустые строки. Оставшиеся можно считать строками кода (достаточно пространное обсуждение подобного вопроса можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444331)).

Следует отметить, что Вам по ходу поиска комментариев придется искать строки (в них не нужно искать комментарии) и кавычки в апострофах ( `'"'` -- поскольку это не начало строки) вне строк. Естественно, внутри комментариев анализ на начало строки не нужен.

Возможно стоит распознавать блоки (в т.ч. вложенные) вида

```
#if 0
...
#endif
```

как своего рода комментарий (учтите, что анализ строк и 
комментариев в них весьма своеобразен, поиграйтесь сами).

--

Что же касается вопроса

> Интересует сама проверка строки (есть ли в ней что-либо из набора
>   выше).

то проще всего использовать функцию [strspn](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html). Что-то в духе

```
if (strspn(input_line, "\t \n{}();\r"))
  puts("Ok, it's c++ codeline");
```

Answer (score 1):

Для решения этой задачи можно использовать регулярные выражения, например таким образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string from;
    std::cin >> from;

    std::ifstream is(from.c_str());

    std::string line;
    std::regex pattern("[{|}|(|)| |;|\\\\t|\\\\n|\\\\r]+");
    std::smatch matches; 

    int counter = 0;
    while (!is.eof()){
       std::getline(is, line);
       int result = std::regex_search(line, matches, pattern);
       if (result)
         counter++;
    }
    std::cout << counter;
}
```

Если же нужно найти управляющие символы \n, \t, \r то регулярное выражение следует записать так:

```
    std::regex pattern("[{|}|(|)| |;|\\t|\\n|\\r]+");
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть [find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать чуть более развёрнутые ответы.